# htaccess and mod_rewrite redirect error

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

on ubuntu 13.04 and apache2 and php 5.4 i got the 404 error.
mod rewrite is enabled on my machine

my .htaccess code is like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/dl/([0-9]+)/$ dl.php?id=$1
</IfModule>
```

and the dl.php is set up for just echo the variables:

```
<?php
print_r($_GET);
?>
```

on output when i will go to this address `http://localhost/digidoc/dl/5` it shows the 404 error

p.s.:the .htaccess file included in digidoc folder and digidoc folder is in web server root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get rid of the leading slash:

```
Options -Multiviews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /digidoc/
    RewriteRule ^dl/([0-9]+)$ dl.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

You should also include a rewrite base as well as making sure that you have multiviews turned off.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
RewriteRule ^/dl/([0-9]+)/$ dl.php?id=$1
```

Into

```
RewriteRule ^/digidoc/dl/([0-9]+)/?$ dl.php?id=$1
```

Notice the ?, so the last slash is optional. Also add `digidoc/` as the rule is applied to the whole url.

Comment: i got same error : The requested URL /digidoc/dl/5 was not found on this server.

Comment: What url are you requesting? `http://localhost/dl/5` or `http://localhost/digidoc/dl/5`?

Comment: the htaccess file included at digidoc folder so i call the `http://localhost/digidoc/dl/5` , i must save the .htaccess in root folder?

Comment: No, that isn't necessary. But you should add the digdoc to the RewriteRule. The rule is applied to the whole url: `RewriteRule ^/digidoc/dl/([0-9]+)/?$ dl.php?id=$1`